# How to use value of a variable from one R file into another

Tags: r

I have a `config.R` file which has variable P.

```
P_val<-function(s){   
if(s==1){    
return(p<-0.01)  
 }  
 else if(s==2){
     return(p<-0.031)  
 }  
 else if(s==3){
     return(p<-0.001)  
 }   
else if(s==4){
     return(p<-0.021) 
  }   
else if(s==5){
     return(p<-0.1)  
 }   
else if(s==6){
     return(p<-0.77)  
 }  
 else if(s==7){
     return(p<-0.35)   
}  
 else if(s==8){
     return(p<-0.66)   
}
 }
```

In my `main.R` file I want to use this P value but the thing is this p variable here is in a loop and I want different value for each loop run. I am showing you a sample demonstration of what I want:

```
  d<-function(num){
for(s in seq(1,8,1)){
  x=2*s ##some variable
  source("config.R")
  P_val(s)
  reset(x,p)
}
reset<-function(x,p){
  l_val= (x/p) * num
  return(l_val)
}
}
```

I am using `source("config.R")` in my `main.R` file but I don't know how to use it as I am getting this error

> Error in reset(x, p) : object 'p' not found

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read on how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also include expected output and code that you have tried so far.

Comment: rather than discussing this unconstructive question through one of the answers, please try to improve the question itself. Add sample data, share what you expect as output etc. Go through SO questions to learn how to construct a question.

Comment: you're not assigning the value returned by the function. Try `p = P_val(s)` ?

Comment: Yes thank you. @Aramis7d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the value p, like so:

```
p <- P_val(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It works. Rookie mistake :) @errantBard

Answer (score 0):

More explanations on the files and relations between `i` and `p` might be helpful here.

Assuming there is a relation between the iteration number `i` and value of `p` you can try defining this relation as a [function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) within the `config.R` file.

Then you just need to `source("config.R")` wihtin your `main.R`, as you're already doing, and make a call to the function from within the iterator whenever needed.

Comment: It seems you're just defining them statically. Have you used a function? pass `i` to the function as an argument, then use `conditional` cases like `if-else` within the function to assign a value to `p` and return this value from the function.

Comment: please edit the question to include the function definitions and such. would be more helpful.

Comment: I did the editing @Aramis7d